# On wired network, linux, set a static IP address if DHCP if fails

Tags: ip, dhcp, wired-networking

At my university office my laptop needs to use a static IP address on a wired network. At home I connect to the router also by cable (saving wireless bandwidth for the rest of the family). This works ok, but I have to manually select the wired network: if I'm at work switching to the static IP address is needed; the default is DHCP. Is there a way to automatically switch to the wired network with static IP if no wired DHCP assigned IP address is obtained?

Comment: I have an idea, but not a specific solution: when the cable is plugged in, a script is automatically run to scan the wifi list and do dhcp if your home wifi is there, if not, set a static address. maybe will inspire others, XD

Comment: Many network configuration tools have hooks for things like this. You can then scan properties of the network (eg: arping to check the MAC address of a router) and do a decision on it. You should state which distribution and especially which network configuration tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to set your home router so its DHCP server
will distribute IP addresses in the same range as that used in the
university.

This way, your static IP address will work both at home and at the
university with no change at all.

Comment: Thanks, I had not thought about this, and it seems to be a good solution. I still need to try it.

Comment: This is only half an answer. The pool of DHCP addresses that the home router uses needs to exclude the (static) IP address already assigned to the laptop.

Comment: @sawdust: Yes, and the netmask should include it all.